# How can I explain to someone that,no one knows what is Allah's decision?

Tags: allah

I know that God Almighty is able to do all thing and I made dua to God to reverse time back till the moment He created the Pen and to change and add many things including life etc.

I told this my mother and she said: "Stop right there.  Not even in millions and trillions years in future God will reverse time back for anyone.  Even if He did, He did with a purpose to show the people that He is able to do all things and that's it.  And if one makes dua to Him, then He'll not reverse the time back."

How can I explain to my Christian mother that one does not know Allah's decision?

Comment: @Kilise Don't ever say this that God didn't know that I would wish for certain things,coz God Almighty knows everything,the past,present and future and He knows when I'm gonna wish a thing also.

Comment: this is what I am saying, if God already know what you would wish for trillion years ago, why would he *now*, turn back the time and grant you the wish? He could have done it trillion years ago since he already knew you would wish something like that.... This kind of thinking will only make you end up in paradoxes

Comment: Please add that hadith or reference of what happened to the prophet so we know what you based your question on

Comment: @Kilise Well,He did this once at the time of prophet Muhammad and prophet Muhammad asked God to reverse time back for a person who didn't payed,so I was thinking that if prophet Muhammad asked why shall I not try?At least I give a shoot.And because I would like to ask Him to reverse time back so that I can have second chance to build a bright near future.

Comment: Could you add the hadith to your question?

Comment: @Kilise Long ago at the time of prophet Muhammad(pbuh)asked a man:Have you prayed Asr something like that,and the man said:No,because I had work to do and then prophet Muhammad asked God Almighty to reverse time back for him so that he can pray the prayer he didn't.I hope it is everything correct as I mentioned here and by the way it is true,which is from Quran

Comment: Try adding references to that hadith, i.e from example [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com) where you can find ahadith, or if you remember the hadith number and collection, that would help.